# Java Map iterate and convert to different form

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi I am using Java and Spring Boot in my project. When calling an external API, it returns `Map<String, Map<String, List<Employees>>>`. I need to convert this to `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>`, from `List<Employees>` to `Map<Employee.phoneNumber, Employee.Name>`. I have implemented code like below,

```
Employee.java
    String Name;
    String phoneNumber;



Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> output = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Map<String, List<Employees>>> allDepSubDepEmployees = <restTemplate external call>;
allDepSubDepEmployees .forEach((k, v) -> {
   v.forEach((k1, v1) -> {
    if (!output.containsKey(k)) {
       output.put(k, new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>());
     }
     if (!output.get(k).containsKey(k1)) {
        output.get(k).put(k1, new HashMap<String, String>());
      }
      v1.stream().forEach(employee -> {
         output.get(k).get(k1).put(employee.getPhoneNumber(), employee.getName())
      }); 
   })
});
```

Using above code I am able to convert but is there a more efficient approach better than this with less number of code ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I believe there is a conciser way. However, they say that code review questions belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions asking for improvements on working code belong on sister site Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would outsource the conversion from `Map<String, List<Employees>>` to  `Map<String, Map<String,String>>` to a method or function in order to increase readability slightly.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Map<String, List<Employees>>> allDepSubDepEmployees = createDummyData();

        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,String>>> result =
            allDepSubDepEmployees.entrySet()
                                 .stream()
                                 .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), convert(e.getValue())))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println(result);

    }

    public static Map<String, Map<String,String>> convert(Map<String, List<Employees>> map) {
        return map.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                                            e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(
                                                    Collectors.toMap(Employees::getPhoneNumber, Employees::getName))));
    }

    private static Map<String, Map<String, List<Employees>>> createDummyData() {
        return Map.of(
                "A", Map.of("a1", List.of(new Employees("100", "employee100"),
                                          new Employees("101", "employee101"),
                                          new Employees("102", "employee102")),
                            "a2", List.of(new Employees("200", "employee200"),
                                          new Employees("201", "employee201"),
                                          new Employees("202", "employee202"))),
                "B", Map.of("b1", List.of(new Employees("300", "employee300"),
                                          new Employees("301", "employee301"),
                                          new Employees("302", "employee302")),
                            "b2", List.of(new Employees("400", "employee400"),
                                          new Employees("401", "employee401"),
                                          new Employees("402", "employee402"))));
    }

    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Employees {
        String phoneNumber;
        String name;
    }
}
```